# How do you know when animation with Snabbt has finished?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying out the animation library Snabbt http://daniel-lundin.github.io/snabbt.js/

I'm enjoying the ease of splitting animation away from the content but how do you wait for the animation to finish before doing something else?  I don't think it has any callbacks, so there's no way to wait for one.

I have a function that uses the Class of elements as a selector.  I animate them with Snabbt but I want to do something else once the animation is finished.

```
function _pulseAllItems() {
  // Fade in and out all elements with 'item' class
  snabbt(document.querySelectorAll('.item'), {
    fromOpacity: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 500,
    springConstant: 1.9,
    springDeceleration: 0.9,
    delay: function(i) {
      return i * 50;
    }
  }).snabbt({
    fromOpacity: 1,
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 500,
    springConstant: 1.9,
    springDeceleration: 0.9,
    delay: function(i) {
      return i * 50;
    }
  });
  // After they have all 'pulsed' do something else.
}
```

I don't really want to use a timer function and hope there is a way to know when it has finished.

Thanks for your help in advance :)

### UPDATE

Thanks Paras !  I found the allDone function near the documentation you mentioned which works a charm.

It's a little update, but thought I would add the function here:

```
function _pulseAllItems() {
  snabbt(document.querySelectorAll('.item'), {
    fromOpacity: 0,
    opacity: 1,
    duration: 500,
    springConstant: 1.9,
    springDeceleration: 0.9,
    delay: function(i) {
      return i * 50;
    }
  }).snabbt({
    fromOpacity: 1,
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 500,
    springConstant: 1.9,
    springDeceleration: 0.9,
    delay: function(i) {
      return i * 50;
    },
    allDone: function(){
      // Do things after animation finish...
    }
  });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the callback function shown in the documentation [here](http://daniel-lundin.github.io/snabbt.js/#usage). Look at the 'complete' function callback. You can do something like

```
     snabbt(element, {
        position: [100, 0, 0],
        rotation: [Math.PI, 0, 0],
        easing: 'ease',
        complete: function(index, total){
          //do something here
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps,

Paras

Comment: Hi Paras,  the documentation you are referring to states it gets called for each item in the list.  I need to know when all are finished.  Thanks for your comment though :)

Comment: I will try and have a look at the 'alldone' function though - so thanks for pointing that bit of the documentation out to me :)

Comment: The documentation contains something for a sequence of items as well.

Comment: The Item Sequence is for the sequence of animations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the thoughts; the 'allDone' function was what I was looking for.